# Java chromedriver flag "--force-dark-mode" not working

Tags: java, selenium

Hei there
I have a small script that opens a website and captures an element by doing a screenshot. Now the probelm is even tho the website is supposed to be in darkmode it opens for a short amount of time in white mode and then the picture is already taken with white mode, which doesnt look as nice.
Now I know of the force darkmode experimental feature which I know fixed this issue. How can I implement this in selenium with java and the chromedriver?
This flag sadly didn't work..

```
options.addArguments("--start-maximized","--headless","--window-size=2560,1440", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments("--force-dark-mode");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: You might need options.setExperimental..... for that... I took a quick look in Chrome's preferences file, though, and couldn't figure out which option it was.

Comment: You can not combine args `--headless` with `--force-dark-mode`.

Comment: Anyone figured out a solution to this?